# String class summation disappears the right operand

Tags: string, json

I intend to create a function to jsify sensors' content and save it on a SD-card or send through a http client. Except for the `Serial.println`'s, the function is transcripted below.

```
String jsonificar(vector<vector<String>> sujeito){
  String json_txt = String(""), chave, valor;
  String chave_str, valor_str;

  json_txt+=String("{");
  for(unsigned int i = 0; i<sujeito.size(); i++){
    if(sujeito[i].size() != 2){
        Serial.println("Cada conteudo deve conter 2 textos!");
    }
    else{
        chave = sujeito[i][0];
        valor = sujeito[i][1];
        Serial.println(chave);
        Serial.println(valor);
        Serial.println(json_txt);
        json_txt += "\\\"";
        Serial.println(json_txt);
        json_txt += chave;
        Serial.println(json_txt);
        json_txt += "\\\"";
        Serial.println(json_txt);
        json_txt += ":";
        Serial.println(json_txt);
        json_txt += "\\\"";
        Serial.println(json_txt);
        json_txt += valor;
        Serial.println(json_txt);
        json_txt += "\\\"";
        Serial.println(json_txt);

        if(i != sujeito.size() - 1){
          json_txt += String(",");
        }
    }
  }

  json_txt+="}";
  Serial.println(json_txt);

  return json_txt;
}
```

The output on serial follows:

```
Output:

Chave1
Valor1
{
{\"
{\"Chave1
{\"Chave1\"
{\"Chave1\":
{\"Chave1\":\"
{\"Chave1\":\"Valor1
{\"Chave1\":\"Valor1\"
Chave2
Valor2
{\"Chave1\":\"Valor1\",
{\"Chave1\":\"Valor1\",\"
{\"Chave1\":\"Valor1\",\"    <===
{\"Chave1\":\"Valor1\",\"\"
{\"Chave1\":\"Valor1\",\"\": <===
{\"Chave1\":\"Valor1\",\"\": <===
{\"Chave1\":\"Valor1\",\"\": <===
{\"Chave1\":\"Valor1\",\"\": <===
{\"Chave1\":\"Valor1\",\"\":}
```

The arrows show the spots where the logs are different from expected: the keys and values provided are "Chave1", "Valor1", "Chave2", "Valor2". So, the key-value should be "Chave2":"Valor2". Would you have a grasp of this behaviour? I look forward for the answer!

Comment: How did you get `std::vector` into Arduino? It doesn't compile for me.

Comment: The same way one would use in default C++ appplication: using namespace std;   You have  answered your own question unpurposely ;P

Comment: The Arduino core implementation for AVR does not have these C++ STL types. Are you using an additional library like https://github.com/mike-matera/ArduinoSTL ?

Comment: Yes, I use `ArduinoSTL`. I also use `PlatformIO` as IDE and it says `vector` comes from `namespace std`.

Comment: You **must** be using this above library, no doubt. It does not work without it. I compiled this code and it ran without an error. Have a look at: https://pastebin.com/LPTYDje5

Comment: Note that you are constructing strings which uses dynamic memory allocation. What MCU are you on? Arduino Uno? You can see that my minimal test sketch works, so if it doesn't in your case, you ran out of memory. What exact sketch are you using?

Comment: `#include <Arduino.h>
#include <unity.h>
#include "../src/utils.h"

vector<String> vetor_auxiliar1, vetor_auxiliar2;
vector<vector<String>> vetor_mestre;
`

Comment: `void test_jsonificar(){
    vetor_auxiliar1.push_back(String("Chave1"));
    vetor_auxiliar1.push_back(String("Valor1"));
    vetor_mestre.push_back(vetor_auxiliar1);

    vetor_auxiliar2.push_back(String("Chave2"));
    vetor_auxiliar2.push_back(String("Valor2"));
    vetor_mestre.push_back(vetor_auxiliar2);

    String resultado, esperado = String("{\"Chave1\":\"Valor1\",\"Chave2\":\"Valor2\"}");
    resultado = jsonificar(vetor_mestre);
    
    TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL(1, esperado.compareTo(resultado));
}
`

Comment: `void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    UNITY_BEGIN();   
}

void loop() {
    RUN_TEST(test_jsonificar);
    UNITY_END(); // stop unit testing
}`

Comment: Okay you should have edited your question with that code but when I run that (wihtout the unity testing framework) I get the behaviour that it crashes after the third iteration (when put into a loop). I would just use the https://github.com/bblanchon/ArduinoJson library to construct these JSON strings in a more memory-efficient way than concatinating `String`s which uses loads of heap (https://pastebin.com/h2eE3sgc)

Comment: Ok, I will do so. Thank you for the consulting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "disappearing string" has the following cause: Out-of-Memory.

You are constructing lots of `String` objects in your code and are concatinating to one. That uses memory on the heap for each `String` (and `realloc()` when the String memory must be expanded).

Consider the following test sketch which includes your code but also adds a memory leak by 150 bytes in each iteration:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <ArduinoSTL.h>
using namespace std;

extern unsigned int __heap_start;
extern void *__brkval;

/*
 * The free list structure as maintained by the
 * avr-libc memory allocation routines.
 */
struct __freelist {
    size_t sz;
    struct __freelist *nx;
};

/* The head of the free list structure */
extern struct __freelist *__flp;

/* Calculates the size of the free list */
int freeListSize() {
    struct __freelist* current;
    int total = 0;
    for (current = __flp; current; current = current->nx) {
        total += 2; /* Add two bytes for the memory block's header  */
        total += (int) current->sz;
    }
    return total;
}

int freeMemory() {
    int free_memory;
    if ((int) __brkval == 0) {
        free_memory = ((int) &free_memory) - ((int) &__heap_start);
    } else {
        free_memory = ((int) &free_memory) - ((int) __brkval);
        free_memory += freeListSize();
    }
    return free_memory;
}

String jsonificar(vector<vector<String>> sujeito) {
    String json_txt = String(""), chave, valor;
    String chave_str, valor_str;

    json_txt += String("{");
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sujeito.size(); i++) {
        if (sujeito[i].size() != 2) {
            Serial.println("Cada conteudo deve conter 2 textos!");
        } else {
            chave = sujeito[i][0];
            valor = sujeito[i][1];
            Serial.println(chave);
            Serial.println(valor);
            Serial.println(json_txt);
            json_txt += "\\\"";
            Serial.println(json_txt);
            json_txt += chave;
            Serial.println(json_txt);
            json_txt += "\\\"";
            Serial.println(json_txt);
            json_txt += ":";
            Serial.println(json_txt);
            json_txt += "\\\"";
            Serial.println(json_txt);
            json_txt += valor;
            Serial.println(json_txt);
            json_txt += "\\\"";
            Serial.println(json_txt);

            if (i != sujeito.size() - 1) {
                json_txt += String(",");
            }
        }
    }

    json_txt += "}";
    Serial.println(json_txt);

    return json_txt;
}

void setup(void) {
    Serial.begin(115200);
}

String myStr = "";

void loop(void) {

    Serial.print(F("Free Memory:"));
    Serial.println(freeMemory());

    //force a memory leak by allocating appending to a global String
    myStr +=
            "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
            "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";

    vector<vector<String>> v =
            { { "Chave1", "Valor1" }, { "Chave2", "Valor2" }, };

    jsonificar(v);
    delay(1000);
}
```

From the output we can see the exact point where we have enough memory and the result is correct, and where we don't have enough memory and the string just "disappears" because there was not enough memory to allocate it:

```
Free Memory:911
Chave1
Valor1
{
{\"
{\"Chave1
{\"Chave1\"
{\"Chave1\":
{\"Chave1\":\"
{\"Chave1\":\"Valor1
{\"Chave1\":\"Valor1\"
Chave2
Valor2
{\"Chave1\":\"Valor1\",
{\"Chave1\":\"Valor1\",\"
{\"Chave1\":\"Valor1\",\"Chave2
{\"Chave1\":\"Valor1\",\"Chave2\"
{\"Chave1\":\"Valor1\",\"Chave2\":
{\"Chave1\":\"Valor1\",\"Chave2\":\"
{\"Chave1\":\"Valor1\",\"Chave2\":\"Valor2
{\"Chave1\":\"Valor1\",\"Chave2\":\"Valor2\"
{\"Chave1\":\"Valor1\",\"Chave2\":\"Valor2\"}
Free Memory:761
Chave1
Valor1
{
{\"
{\"Chave1
{\"Chave1\"
{\"Chave1\":
{\"Chave1\":\"
{\"Chave1\":\"Valor1
{\"Chave1\":\"Valor1\"
Chave2
Valor2
{\"Chave1\":\"Valor1\",
{\"Chave1\":\"Valor1\",\"
{\"Chave1\":\"Valor1\",\"Chave2
{\"Chave1\":\"Valor1\",\"Chave2\"
{\"Chave1\":\"Valor1\",\"Chave2\":
{\"Chave1\":\"Valor1\",\"Chave2\":\"
{\"Chave1\":\"Valor1\",\"Chave2\":\"
{\"Chave1\":\"Valor1\",\"Chave2\":\"
{\"Chave1\":\"Valor1\",\"Chave2\":\"
```